# Solving a differential equation of order two

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

I can not to solve the following equation
$$ y^{ ''}(t) + \left( \lambda^{2} -  \frac{2}{\sinh^{2}(t)}  \right) y(t) = 0, \quad \mbox{with} \, t>0 $$
where $\lambda \in \mathbb C$.

Someone can help me!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: y(t), not y(r), I presume ?

Comment: If I remember well, 1st pretend the parameter A in y"(t)+ A(t)y(t) =0 is a constant, find the solution, and reinject it in the equation now assuming it varies with t.

Comment: have you asked WolframAlpha to get a powerful hint?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: Mathematica gives a horrible expression involving the hyperbolic tangent and the Appel function.

Comment: yes i know it and from where do you that isn't the right solution to your problem?

Comment: @Fabrice NEYRET: For $A$ is a is a constant, $y"(t)+ A y(t) =0$ has for solution $y(t) = c_1 \sin(\sqrt{A}t) + c_2 \cos(\sqrt{A}t) $, so $y(t) = c_1 \sin(t\sqrt{A(t)}) + c_2 \cos(t\sqrt{A(t)}) $ where $A(t) = \lambda^{2} -  \frac{2}{\sinh^{2}(t)}$ is not it? but it is very horrible !!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B6schl%E2%80%93Teller_potential

Comment: well, yes, maybe your problem provider is a sadist ! :-) Now the receipe say recompute y"+Ay, assuming c1 and c2 are not constants. Well, seems like it 's getting worse and another way would be welcomed. sorry ! :-/

Comment: The problem gets much simpler if you rewrite it in terms of the hyperbolic cosine before solving the ODE.

Comment: @David Scott Kirby,  is what I have to replace $\sinh^2$ by $\cosh^2 - 1$ in the equation, or what?

Comment: Why you don't try to use the link i posted? Replace $t=tanh(x)$ and try to bring the resulting equation into Legendre form

Comment: @tired Does this really have large difference? Both approaches relate to Associated Legendre function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the substitution $s(t) = \cosh(t)$ and write $y(t) = Y(s(t))$. We thus find for $Y$ the differential equation
\begin{equation}
(1-s^2)Y''(s) - s Y'(s) + \left(\frac{2}{1-s^2}+\lambda^2\right) Y(s) = 0,
\end{equation}
which is (a form of the) the associated Legendre equation. In this case, we can
obtain the ‘proper’ associated Legendre equation by introducing
$$\zeta(s) = (s^2-1)^{-\frac{1}{4}} Y(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sinh t}} \,Y(\cosh t)$$
In fact, plugging $Y(s) = (s^2-1)^{\frac{1}{4}} \zeta(s)$ into the equation for $Y$ yields the associated Legendre equation, multiplied by a prefactor $-(s^2-1)^\frac{1}{4}$, with $\nu(\nu+1) = -\lambda^2-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\mu^2 = \frac{9}{4}$.

Eventually, we obtain
\begin{align}
y(t) &= \sqrt{\sinh t} \left[c_1 P_{i \lambda - \frac{1}{2}}^{2-\frac{1}{2}}(\cosh t) + c_2 Q_{i \lambda - \frac{1}{2}}^{2-\frac{1}{2}}(\cosh t) \right]\\
&=  \sqrt{\sinh t} \left[c_1 P_{i \lambda - \frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}}(\cosh t) + c_2 Q_{i \lambda - \frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{3}{2}}(\cosh t) \right]
\end{align}
where $P_\nu^\mu(z)$ and $Q_\nu^\mu(z)$ are the standard solutions to the associated Legendre equation given by
$$\left(  \left(1-x^{2}\right) \frac{d^2}{dx^2}-2x\frac{d}{dx} +\left(\nu(\nu+1) -\frac{\mu^2}{1-x^2} \right)    \right)w=0$$
Finally, My question, is what we can write this solution in terms of elementary functions ($\sinh, \cosh ..)$, without intervening the Legendre function.

Thanks in advance